# Select Scene Collection in Outliner, then paste collection in clipboard

Tags: python, collections, outliner

I am trying to use this operator: `bpy.ops.outliner.id_paste()` to paste a collection I have copied in the clipboard, and my problem is setting the right context, because I keep getting this error:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.outliner.id_paste.poll() failed,
> context is incorrect

This has been my current approach. I suspect it might be solved by being able to select the scene collection, but I have tried almost everything I could find.

```
override = bpy.context.copy()
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
        override['area'] = area

bpy.ops.outliner.id_paste()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add):

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type != 'OUTLINER':
        continue
    with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obj, area=area):
        bpy.ops.outliner.id_paste()
    break
```

Comment: Wow, okay yeah this gets me pretty close, now this actually pastes the collection into the outliner, fantastic, the only problem now is that it pastes it to whatever is active I think? but it should always paste to the scene collection. I am creating a script that sends collections from one file to another, and I won't always know what is active, so it should just default to scene collection. Also do you know how to get a reference to the collection that was just pasted?

Comment: Yeah you need to set the *Scene Collection* active but there seems to be no way to do that via script, at least I'm struggling to find a way. Have you found a way?

Comment: No I haven't either, all I have is the fact that this exists `bpy.context.scene.collection`, but no way of getting me there. I think you got as close as possible right now, but I might do the whole operation a different way, by simply pasting the objects and then creating a new collection for the objects, then I can control that collection.